# Custom Plotly Markers based on variable value

Tags: python, plotly

I am using the following code to create a simple plotly line chart in Python. I have two variables (at the bottom of the code):

```
ctime
amount
```

ctime just using the current time for each element in amount; there are 10 times
amount is a contained of amounts ranging from 0-1000; the are ten amounts

I want to color my plot markers in the following way:

amount is less than 300; that specific marker for that value will be green
amount is between 300 and 400; that specific marker for that value will be yellow
amount is greater than 400; that specific marker for that value will be red

Is there any way I can build in a conditional type handler for this?

```
layout = Layout(
    title='Current Amount',
    titlefont=Font(
        family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
        size=17,
        color='#444'
    ),
    font=Font(
        family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
        size=12,
        color='#444'
    ),
    showlegend=True,
    autosize=True,
    width=803,
    height=566,
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title='Time',
        titlefont=Font(
            family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
            size=14,
            color='#444'
        ),
        range=[1418632334984.89, 1418632334986.89],
        domain=[0, 1],
        type='date',
        rangemode='normal',
        autorange=True,
        showgrid=False,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=True,
        autotick=True,
        nticks=0,
        ticks='inside',
        showticklabels=True,
        tick0=0,
        dtick=1,
        ticklen=5,
        tickwidth=1,
        tickcolor='#444',
        tickangle='auto',
        tickfont=Font(
            family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
            size=12,
            color='#444'
        ),
        mirror='allticks',
        linecolor='rgb(34,34,34)',
        linewidth=1,
        anchor='y',
        side='bottom'
    ),
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title='GHI (W/m2)',
        titlefont=Font(
            family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
            size=14,
            color='#444'
        ),
        range=[-5.968375815056313, 57.068375815056314],
        domain=[0, 1],
        type='linear',
        rangemode='normal',
        autorange=True,
        showgrid=False,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=True,
        autotick=True,
        nticks=0,
        ticks='inside',
        showticklabels=True,
        tick0=0,
        dtick=1,
        ticklen=5,
        tickwidth=1,
        tickcolor='#444',
        tickangle='auto',
        tickfont=Font(
            family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
            size=12,
            color='#444'
        ),
        exponentformat='B',
        showexponent='all',
        mirror='allticks',
        linecolor='rgb(34,34,34)',
        linewidth=1,
        anchor='x',
        side='left'
    ),
    legend=Legend(
        x=1,
        y=1.02,
        traceorder='normal',
        font=Font(
            family='"Open sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
            size=12,
            color='#444'
        ),
        bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        bordercolor='#444',
        borderwidth=0,
        xanchor='left',
        yanchor='auto'
    )
)


new_data = Scatter(x=ctime, y=amount)
data = Data( [ new_data ] )
```

Answer (score 8):

So for your use case, you need to use the property `marker.color` under line chart, which is given in the official documentation as.

> **color (color)** 
>  Sets the marker color. It accepts either a specific color or an array of numbers that are mapped to the
>   colorscale relative to the max and min values of the array or relative
>   to `cmin` and `cmax` if set.

Read more [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-color)

Below is a simple working example demonstrating your use case, please apply it to your solution and let me know if your issue is resolved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900]

# function below sets the color based on amount
def SetColor(x):
    if(x < 300):
        return "green"
    elif(x >= 300 | x <= 400):
        return "yellow"
    elif(x > 400):
        return "red"

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    marker = dict(color=list(map(SetColor, y)))
)

iplot([trace], filename='basic-line')
```

**Output:**

[image]